# Does there exist an explicit formula that expresses $p_{n+1}-p_{n}$ in terms of $p_n$, the $n$th prime number?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-gaps

Given the $n$th prime number, is it possible to express explicitly a function $\phi:P \mapsto \mathbb{N}$, where $P$ is the set of all prime numbers, such that $\phi(p_n)$ gives the prime gap after $p_n$?

Comment: Even if such function exists it must be very "inconvenient" to use. Mathematicians still do not know if there are infinitely many prime twins: so looking at this function it's not so easy even to tell if it's value can be 2 for an arbitrarily large argument. Must be some very ugly function, I do not think it exists.

Comment: $p_2-p_1=1$ and $p_{n+1}-p_{n}=2$ for other **twin primes**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think so. Because otherwise we would have a function which gives us all the prime numbers. It is easily seen, that we would have $$p_{n + 1} = p_n + \phi(p_n)$$ and inductively we would get every prime number.